# Can a C++ addon in Node.js override some V8 class or method?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I'm not a C++ programmer, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Suppose that I want to change a particular behavior in V8. Of course I can change it inside `deps/v8` and then build Node.js from source. But I'm searching if there is an easier way.

Can I write a C++ addon to override what I want in V8?

For example, could I create an empty addon:

```
namespace MY_EMPTY_ADDON
{

  void init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports, v8::Local<v8::Object> module)
  {
    // empty
  }

  NODE_MODULE(MY_EMPTY_ADDON, init)
}
```

Then, at the same file add some thing like this:

```
namespace v8
{
  namespace internal
  {
    // here I do my changes
  }
}
```

Could this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. C++ does not allow monkey-patching in the way JavaScript does. You cannot override another module's/library's functions from the outside.